# getting values that do not have a tie

Tags: mysql

how can I ignore all the duplicating records and get only those which do not have a tie in mysql for example; from the following data set;

```
1|item1| data1
2|item1| data2
3|item2| data3
4|item3| data4
```

I want to get this get this kind of results;

```
3|item2| data3
4|item3| data4
```

Comment: Could you define *tie* ? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: what I mean is that I don't want to get any of those duplicating records that is when the query runs and finds two common rows in a column, it should jump them all. when I use group by or distinct they give one element of the duplicates which I don't wan, I want a kind of 'jump' where a value exists within the column

Answer (score 0):

Since you laking any form of table definition, i assume 3 columns:

```
# table: test
# - id
# - name
# - value

SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY NAME HAVING count(*) = 1

# result:
3   item2   data3
4   item3   data4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y.id <> x.id AND y.item = x.item 
  WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```